# Postgresql difference between two columns dates?

Tags: postgresql

```
Username    DateStart  DateFinish
James       2017-07-01 2017-09-14
Luigi       2017-08-02 2017-09-18
Francesco   2017-09-03 2017-10-25
```

How calculate with sql difference between two date columns in days?

Comment: `select *, "DateFinish" - "DateStart" `?..

Answer (score 6):

You can simply subtract them like

```
select "DateFinish"::date - "DateStart"::date;
```

And if the dates column are of datatype date then you can simply do:

```
select "DateFinish" - "DateStart"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the difference in a number (10 instead of a date value that has 10 days in it), you can obtain it with:

```
select extract(day from "DateFinish" - "DateStart")
```

Comment: The `extract` is unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It extracts the number of days between 2 dates and creates a column called "days":

```
select extract(day from DateFinish - DateStart) as days from MyTable;
```

Comment: The `extract` is unnecessary